# Show prices excluding Tax/VAT but calculate and display only on checkout

Tags: commerce

In case of B2B store I need to display all prices **without** VAT taxes. But taxes must be shown on cart and during checkout process. What's the good way for this?

I use commerce_vat.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, all replies/comments are welcomed!

1. Edit rule "***Calculate tax***" *(admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/commerce_vat_calculate)* and add conditions for check if "***Entity has field***": **commerce_customer_billing**, **commerce_customer_address**
2. For not showing tax on cart (only on checkout): Add condition of type "**NOT Data comparison**": "**Data to compare: [site:current-page:path], Operator: is one of, Data value: cart**"
3. Use hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter() for edit labels (incl./excl. Tax) depending on whether the customer is liable for Tax/VAT or not.

---

Result in checkout process with a customer liable for VAT:

[image]